# Как запустить javascript повторно без перезагрузки страницы?

Tags: javascript

Всем привет! Помогите решить задачу: Есть прогресс бар и 2 кнопки, первая запускает его, вторая очищает. Как сделать так, чтобы при нажатии на кнопку Clear прогресс бар можно было снова запустить без перезагрузки страницы.

```js
var start = 0;
var br = document.getElementById('bar');

function uProgress(time) {
  var btn = document.getElementById('click').onclick = function() {
    var timerId = setInterval(function() {
      if (start <= 100) {
        br.value = start;
        start++;
      } else {
        clearInterval(timerId);
      }
    }, time);
  }
  document.getElementById('clear').onclick = function() {
    if (start >= 100) {
      br.value = 0;
    }
  };
};

uProgress(100);
```

```css
.btn-wrapper {
  margin: 5px auto;
  width: 50%;
}

#click,
#clear {
  display: inline-block;
}

#bar {
  display: inline-block;
  width: 350px;
}

.wrap {
  max-width: 350px;
  height: auto;
}
```

```html
<div class="wrap">
  <progress id="bar" value="0" max="100"></progress>
  <div class="btn-wrapper">
    <button id="click">Click function</button>
    <button id="clear">Clear</button>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Начните с исправления опечатки в cleanInterval

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```js
var start = 0;
var br = document.getElementById('bar');

function uProgress(time) {
  var btn = document.getElementById('click').onclick = function() {
    var timerId = setInterval(function() {
      if (start <= 100) {
        br.value = start;
        start++;
      } else {
        clearInterval(timerId);
      }
    }, time);
  }
  document.getElementById('clear').onclick = function() {
    if (start >= 100) {
      br.value = 0;
      start = 0; // НУЖНО ОБНУЛИТЬ ЕЩЕ ЭТО <<<<
    }
  };
};

uProgress(100);
```

```css
.btn-wrapper {
  margin: 5px auto;
  width: 50%;
}

#click,
#clear {
  display: inline-block;
}

#bar {
  display: inline-block;
  width: 350px;
}

.wrap {
  max-width: 350px;
  height: auto;
}
```

```html
<div class="wrap">
  <progress id="bar" value="0" max="100"></progress>
  <div class="btn-wrapper">
    <button id="click">Click function</button>
    <button id="clear">Clear</button>
  </div>
</div>
```